# local server says "stopping, synchronized." after upgrading to new Cloud tools plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse, google-cloud-tools

I am running my local development in Eclipse Neon. I have this issue where the local server says "stopping, synchronized" and I made sure it is not running, killed all processes and still, the issue persists.

I previously had Google Plugin for Eclipse, now upgraded to the new Cloud Tools for Eclipse Plugin and since then this happened. I even upgraded my eclipse to latest Oxygen and still the state of my local server for any port is not starting up.

Any ideas will help me a lot, much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you are hitting https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2727 or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1964. If so, they have been fixed in the latest release. Please upgrade CT4E and try again. If the problem persists and you can reproduce it, it is best to open a new GitHub issue using the "Submit Issue or Feedback" menu item from the main GCP toolbar icon you can find in Eclipse.

Comment: Oops, it seems like the fix for https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1964 has not been released yet. Anyway, please let us know if you are hitting any of the said issues.

Lastly, if you want to kill the process, make sure you kill the process you find with "ps aux | grep DevAppServerMain" on the command line. That should make the server status "stopped, synchronized".

Comment: I appreciate your replies. I am not having any errors in the code I believe it is happening only for App Engine Standard Server running on default port 8080 through my eclipse IDE, I was able to start the server through command line, > mvn appengine:devserver_start.

Comment: If you are still interested in resolving the issue in Eclipse, consider filing a bug (GitHub issue) using the "Submit Issue or Feedback" with more detailed information. Thanks.

Comment: @ChanseokOh, I think the info you are providing in your comments could be quite useful for others. Could you please post it as an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be hitting https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2727 or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1964. They have been fixed since Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.6.0, so please upgrade and try again.

If none of these seem to affect you, and if your problem persists and you can reproduce it, it is best to open a new GitHub issue using the "Submit Issue or Feedback" menu item from the main GCP toolbar icon you can find in Eclipse and provide more detailed information.

Lastly, if you want to kill the local dev appserver process, make sure you kill the process you find, for example, with `ps aux | grep DevAppServerMain` on the command line. Once the process is killed, the server status in Eclipse should change to "stopped, synchronized".